# What happens if I set HttpGetEnabled = false

Tags: .net, wcf, binding, metadata, wcf-binding

I am confused with Metadata publish concept.

If in a WCF Service config file I had written :

```
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
```

No matter it is true or false. When I tried to give service reference in a client application using "Add Service Reference..." and clicked on "Discover", I am able to retrieve Service Reference.

But when removed the following two lines: -

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexBasicHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
```

Now after that when I tried to give reference in a client application using "Add Service Reference...." and clicked on "Discover", I am **NOT** able to retrieve Service Reference....

Now can anyone tell me what exactly it means.
Why after setting it False it is still allowing to set reference. And why after removing those lines it is not allowing to set reference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

MEX and WSDL are two different schemes to tell potential clients about the structure of your service. So you can choose to either make your service contracts public as "metadata exchance format" (MEX) or in the "[web service description language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wsdl)" (WSDL) -- the latter being accessible via HTTP(s).

Thus in order to generate proxies, you need meta data information. When you remove the serviceMetadata-line you say you are not providing meta data in WSDL format.

But the line before, publishing your metadata in MEX, is still active, thus you can generate a proxy from those metadata.

From those follows naturally that when you provide neither WSDL nor MEX formatted information, you cannot generate a proxy.

As Joel C correctly pointed out, the bindings are a(n almost) orthogonal concept. Whether you allow clients to talk to you via basic HTTP, ws HTTP, net named pipes or crystal balls is quite not dependent on how you publish your services.

The [WCF security guidance project](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/) and / or MS ["practises and patterns" for WCF security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949034.aspx) might provide deeper insight.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question: _"What happens if I set HttpGetEnabled = false?"_, does it?

Answer (score 6):

You're adding a service reference, which generates a proxy based on Metadata Exchange (mex). The httpGetEnabled configuration lets you set an http endpoint that would allow a non-mex proxy to be generated using WSDL, such as a legacy .NET webservice proxy. They are different protocols, controlled by different settings. I believe if you were to have `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:8080/SampleService?wsdl"/>` you could add a web service reference from .NET 2.0, which you would be unable to do using the configuration `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>`.

Comment: That means by specifying "httpGetEnabled = true" will make my WCF Service be consumed as webservice too. If yes, then what is the use of "BasicHttpBinding"? As the main advantage of using BasicHttpBinding is to make your WCF Service available to older version and can be consumed as webservice (feature called as backward compatibility i guess, i m not much sure of it), Would you please let us know what exactly then the difference/co-relation between "HttpGetEnabled" and "BasicHttpBinding". If they are co-related then why we should use "HttpGetEnabled=true" line, when I am using "WsHttpBinding"

Comment: How your WCF service communicates with other processes (its endpoint binding) and how it exposes metadata about itself (its metadata configuration) are independent of one another. It makes sense to expose the metadata as WSDL (using `httpGetEnabled="true"` and an `httpGetUrl`) if you plan to access the service as a SOAP web service (using an endpoint configured with `WsHttpBinding`), either setting can be used without the other.

Comment: Then why after removing the following two lines: -

<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexBasicHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>

Why it is not allowing me to give reference in a client application.(I don't wanna use it as webservice)
I feel the exposing ServiceMetadata is somewhere inter-related with WCF Communication. As without metadata client can't establish communication. As client application must know the type and other component of the service to establish communication which possible with metadata only

Comment: It's only related to the discovery aspect of WCF. You can't generate a proxy without it. If you're generating a WCF proxy, that will use the MetadataExchange configuration; if you're using a WSDL-based proxy, that will use the httpGetEnabled setting. But once you have the proxy, either should work to actually *use* the service, those settings should only affect the ability to generate your proxy.