# net.tcp, The socket connection was aborted

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-services

i created the project which contains  windows service (windowsservices.cs) and i added wcf contracts and service file in that class (windowservices.cs). its app.config file contains

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="WindowsService1.Service1Behavior"
    name="AgentSvcImpl">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="nethttpendpoint" contract="IAgentWinService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="nethttpmetadataendpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8011/AgentSvcImpl" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

and in the  windows service onstart method i entered following code:

```
    ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
        //Create a URI to serve as the base address
        Uri httpUrl = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8011/AgentSvcImpl");
        //Create ServiceHost
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WindowsService1.AgentSvcImpl), httpUrl);
        //Add a service endpoint
         serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WindowsService1.IAgentWinService), new NetTcpBinding(), "");
        //Enable metadata exchange
         ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
         smb.HttpGetEnabled = false;
         serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        //Start the Service
        serviceHost.Open();
```

when i am starting this service in services.msc, it started well. but when i try to add service reference it gives following error.

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8011/AgentSvcImpl'.
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:04:59.0054016'.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

how to resolve this?

Comment: This problem may be due to connection not shutdown properly , but cannot be confirmed . 
To get a clear picture of what is going on you may have to set up tracing for both the client and the service. In order to view the traces you would use SvcTraceViewer which should be in the 'Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin' or 'Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin' folder. If you have to trace both the client and the service you can open both files together in SvcTraceViewer using the File / Add menu.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem - service name and contract without namespace:

```
<service ... name="WindowsService1.AgentSvcImpl" ... contract="WindowsService1.IAgentWinService">
```

If not:
try to create new Timer within WCF Service Implementation (AgentSvcImpl) Class Scope with some  non-infinite interval (1 sec for ex.) and empty OnTimer handler.
And [Configure Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to explore more

Comment: What's the purpose of that empty timer?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post : [What happens if I set HttpGetEnabled = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671885/what-happens-if-i-set-httpgetenabled-false)

I guess u will need to activate the HttpGetEnabled property of the behavior:

```
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
```

Hope will help.