# WSDL does not appear with published web service to remote website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I spent the better part of this weekend trying to get the sample I found here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12PGpwy8SUY

To be used outside of the realm of localhost, because everything, and every sample works great when it's run with localhost. I'd like to try using it with my website. My web host allows for Frontpage Extensions. I am using Dev studio pro 2008 to publish the web service to my domain.

What I cannot get to work is using the URL of the sample `palindromes.asmx` to be accepted as a service reference in a C# windows form. When I put in the domain:

`example.com/Palindromes.asmx`

as the service reference to add in the C# win form project, I get:

> The document at the url example.com/Palindromes.asmx was not recognized as a known document type.
>
> The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
>
> - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2.'.
> - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1, 2).'.

Along with some other bits of errors that Google has me (possibly) going down various unrelated rabbit holes.

Yet, if I go to the sample web service, right click the `.asmx` and view in browser, the local host with port and respective `.asmx` file comes up with everything. I then take that URL, plug it in as described above to the C# win form project, all is good. I can run the client locally, and as long as the browser is running the localhost, I can play.

So what am I missing with getting this published properly?

Comment: is `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>` set in the webservices web.config?

Comment: Hi. I don't see that tag in my web.config file. I read up a little on httpGetEnabled since your question and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522493/what-was-the-difference-between-wsdl-mex-endpoint-in-wcf   I will also mention, if it has any bearnig, I am using .NET 3.5

Comment: I didn't have an ASP.NET enabled website from my ISP. As soon as I upgraded to their ASP.NET plan, it worked.