# Want to understand httpGetEnabled and Mex Endpoint

Tags: wcf

i often saw people design their web service with both httpGetEnabled and Mex Endpoint but i do not know like

1) why mex endpoint is require ? what it does ? if we omit mex endpoint then what will occur ? if i omit mex endpoint then any .net application or java application could call my web service? help me the real usage of mex endpoint like when it is required and when not ?

2) what is httpGetEnabled

if i omit httpGetEnabled then any .net application or java application could call my web service?

any .net client can add web reference of my web service if httpGetEnabled is set false of does not exist? what is the default value of httpGetEnabled ?

what httpGetEnabled does ? please explain the usage httpGetEnabled with example or scenario.

thanks

Comment: See http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/08/10/wsdl-vs-mex-knockout-or-tie/

Answer (score 1):

[MEX and WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671885/what-happens-if-i-set-httpgetenabled-false) are two different schemes to tell potential clients about the structure of your service. So you can choose to either make your service contracts public as "metadata exchance format" (MEX) or in the "web service description language" (WSDL) -- the latter being accessible via HTTP(s).

Thus in order to generate proxies, you need meta data information. When you remove the serviceMetadata-line you say you are not providing meta data in WSDL format.

But the line before, publishing your metadata in MEX, is still active, thus you can generate a proxy from those metadata.

From those follows naturally that when you provide neither WSDL nor MEX formatted information, you cannot generate a proxy.

Comment: r u trying to say if people remove mex endpoint then client will not be able to create proxy? httpgetenable not allow client to generate proxy?

Comment: I honestly don't recall answering this question. Nor do I know the details of this topic. I'm curious if someone used my profile for this...